# Compressing a dynamically linked armeabi-v7a executable with UPX

Tags: android-ndk, dynamic-linking, upx

Is it possible to compress a dynamically linked `armeabi-v7a` executable with UPX?

I'm building using `ndk-build (r20b)` and UPX always throws an `UnknownExecutableFormatException` exception unless I add `APP_LDFLAGS += -static` to my module `Android.mk`. This, however, is not something I can do as other parts of my code (an HTTP client) use `getaddrinfo` and `gethostbyname` which require libc to be dynamically linked and result in segmentation faults if I link statically. I'm building without `-fPIE`.

I saw a few threads online that discuss dynamically linked executable compression for Windows .exe files, however, I wasn't able to find anything on this when it comes to an `armeabi-v7a` executable.

Is this even possible? If not, please suggest another binary packer that can do this, if there exists one.